# "compression" transform

Tags: terminology, signal-processing

Is there a mathematical transform that cuts off a signal at two extreme values? Here is code to do what I want:

```
def validTrans(inputValue, upper, lower):
if inputValue > upper:
   return upper
elif inputValue < lower:
   return lower
else:
   return inputValue
```

It seems common enough to need to compress a range (alternatively put, cut off extreme values at some threshold) that I thought this might have a name, like `"someGuysNameTransform(input, u, l)"`. I can do this using a lambda function if needed, just wondering if this is reinventing the wheel.

Edit: nothing here seems to be it http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_transforms

Comment: So you are asking if it already has a name?

Comment: But it is a trivial function, which you actually defined in the question. Why do you want another one from a library which (if it exists) will have the same computational cost?

Comment: In numeric/signal flowcharts, such a function is typically called a "limiter", a "clipper", a "clamp", or a "saturation block".

Comment: I guess I just prefer using standard libraries when possible for cleanliness reasons instead of reinventing many small wheels, and it seemed common enough/applicable enough that it probably exists. I could also write my own function called `abs`, but wouldn't you rather just call `math.abs()`?

Comment: Also, I think that when I go to write up my methodology, its cleaner to say "we apply the `blah` transform to the input" rather than "heres a function we ran on the input:"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In signal processing it's called [clipping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clipping_(audio)).

Comment: Because I am actually doing this with voltage, this seems perfect! However, that article only seems to discuss the upper limit case. Regardless, thanks for the pointer!

Comment: @Tommy The pictures in the article show both the top and bottom clipped.

Answer (score 1):

This is most often (in my experience) referred to as [clamping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clamping_%28graphics%29) the input value.

Comment: This also is perfect. I only accepted clipping since I am actually working with signals and it seems thats the industry term.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is fine. If you insist on using fancy functions, then notice that an equivalent formulation would be:

```
def validTrans(inputValue, upper, lower):
    temp = max(lower, inputValue)
    return min(upper,       temp)
```

Translating to absolute values, we can use something like:

```
def validTrans(inputValue, upper, lower):
    temp = (lower + inputValue + abs(lower - inputValue)) / 2
    return (upper +       temp - abs(upper -       temp)) / 2
```